# i am using emoji module to print emoji. but it is not working

Tags: python, module, emoji

I am using emoji module to print emoji, but it is not working. I am using this code

```
print(emoji.emojize('python is:thumbs_up:'))
```

and it shows the following error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f44d' in position 9: character maps to

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,and let me know

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize("python is :thumbsup:",use_aliases=True))
```

Explanation:
In OP , it was written as ":thumbs_up:" instead of :thumbsup:, only valid words can be printed as emojis,
in the backend, the module just scrapes from the Unicode Consortium’s website and prints the appropriate value.
https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/ this is the cheat sheet for emoji module.

Answer (score 0):

The use_aliases argument is deprecated, and replaced with mentioning language as 'alias' - using emoji version 2.9.0

```py
emoji.emojize("python is cold :panda::cold_face:", language='alias')

# Output: 'python is cold '
```

Hope it helps :)

Ref: https://pypi.org/project/emoji/

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this by implementing try and except. Since there's two types of emojis that we're focusing on - en and alias. Refer to the code below

```
import emoji

x = input("Input: ")

try:
    x = emoji.emojize(x)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    x = emoji.emojize(x, language = "alias")

print(x)
```