# Python code running in VS Code terminal but throwing error in output tab

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, unicode, character-encoding, emoji

I'm trying to run a simple Python code in VS Code that runs successfully in the terminal but throws an error in the output tab.

```
import emoji

print(emoji.emojize('I :red_heart: Python!'))
```

This is the terminal result:

```
>>> import emoji
>>> print(emoji.emojize('I :red_heart: Python!'))
I ❤️ Python!
```

This is the error shown in the Output tab of VS Code once I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\subhr\OneDrive - University of St. Thomas\Python Practice\emoji_demo.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(emoji.emojize('I :red_heart: Python!'))
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2-3: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm using the Code Runner for Visual Studio Code extension.

Comment: Open the file, it should say `UTF-8` in the bottom right of the vscode window

Comment: To be able to find the cause: could you test this: `print(b'I \xe2\x9d\xa4\xef\xb8\x8f Python!'.decode('utf-8')`)? It should give the same result. If this works, the problem was in your file encoding. If this doesn't work, the problem is in your output terminal and you should search how to change the character encoding for that terminal.

Comment: Maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/a/65174809/14141223 ?

Comment: Make sure UTF-8 Encoding is used. As Freddy mentioned in the comment, I will just add a way to check it instantly. Add .encode("utf-8") in your print statement. If it runs correctly, you have the answer.

Comment: I'm using code runner extension for my vs code. I think the plugin has a bug.

Comment: @Innomight, using `.encode()` in the print statement doesn't work. (We're not talking about Python 2.x I assume). print needs a string, otherwise it prints the representation (`repr()`), which is different.

Comment: Try disabling your extension, and click the built-in triangle (run button) in the top right of the python window. Or try using `python run x.py` in the integrated terminal

Comment: I tried `.encode("utf-8")` and also `use_aliases=True` and none of them worked.

Comment: Your file looks to be encoded in `cp1252`. As it's mentioning `File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py"` in your error

Comment: See [the vs-code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v0_3_0#:~:text=You%20can%20view%20the%20file,Then%20choose%20an%20encoding.) on encoding if you're having trouble seeing what type of file it is

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan It is UTF-8 file. I can see it in the bottom.

Comment: I guess it's indeed a bug in your extension then. This shouldn't be necessary, but you could try to add this at the *first* line of your script: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`. Maybe the plugin recognizes this and it might work.

Comment: Try re-writing your string `I :red_heart: Python!` without copy pasting

Comment: None of the above suggestions worked and the `pip3.10 install -U emoji` fetched "Requirement Satisfied" message.

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors, try:

1. Disabling any runner extensions ("*code runner*")
2. Confirming the file is in `UTF-8` format [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v0_3_0#_file-encoding)
3. Updating your library `pip3 install -U emoji`
4. Install the [gremlins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nhoizey.gremlins) extention to search for bad characters
5. Re-writing your code (not copy pasting)

Comment: Strangely, I just ran into the exact inverse issue. The _output_ tab gave me correct results whilst running my code with the terminal enabled gave me an issue "Folder not found". After disabling the Code Runner extension, the problem got fixed! Could this be a conflict between extensions? Why code-runner doesn't work as intended with some languages? (C++ in my case)

Comment: @DanielMelendrez, great question. I have no idea unfortunately, you can open or fin an issue [on github](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues) if you would like to discuss this issue with the developers

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/365) with the Code Runner extension (see also [this issue](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/556)).

The recommended work-around there is to use the below setting (File->Preference->Settings) to run code in Integrated Terminal:

```json
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that necessarily doesn't fix the issue. Once I disabled the "code runner" extension on vs code, I ran the code again but this time it showed a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'emoji'". I then changed the interpreter on the command palette from my virtual environment Python to Global Python and then running the code worked like a charm. Although, I still haven't figured out why my code was throwing an error as it is.

Comment: It might not be necessary to fully disable the extension. See my answer. Let me know if this works, since I currently cannot test it myself.